# I've got an uniterable array which's created by fetching data from the server

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, async-await, fetch

**The array I've created doesn't display properly on the console and I can't iterate it.**

I fetch some data from the NodeJs server and I create objects through a class. Like:

```
 const listBooks = async function() {
        await fetch("/listBooks",{
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/JSON'
            }
        }).then((res) => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            for(let book of data) new createBook(book,heads).addtoTable()
        })
    }()
```

The 'heads' is an array that enables me to check if the properties of books match with ones I determined, because I print them in a table.

In this class (in the addtoTable() function) I also add the 'book' objects into another array which's named 'books' through the 'push' method. But at the end of the script, when I try to print the 'books' array, I get such an array uniterable:

[image]

Not like this (  Array(array length) [items]  )
[image]

When I try to iterate it through for...in or for...of the loop, I got nothing. How can I fix this problem?

The class:

```
class createBook {
        constructor (book, heads) {
            this.book = new Object
            this.list = list
            for (let pm in book) {
                if(heads.find(({code}) => code === pm)) this.book[pm] = book[pm]
            }
        }

        addtoTable () {
            books.push(this.book)
            
            const bookListCon = document.querySelector(".bookListCon .bookList")
    
            var line = document.createElement("div")
            line.classList.add("listLine")
            line.setAttribute("id",this.book.id)
            
            for (const head of heads) {
                if (!head.show) continue
                var cell = document.createElement("div")
                cell.classList.add("listCell")
                var span = document.createElement("span")
                span.innerText = (this.book[head.code].length > 20) ? this.book[head.code].substring(0,20) + "..." : this.book[head.code]
                span.setAttribute("title",this.book[head.code])
                cell.appendChild(span)
                line.appendChild(cell)
            }
            
            bookListCon.appendChild(line)
            
            const addUpdate = document.querySelectorAll(".form_addBook .fline > input")
            line.addEventListener("click",()=>{
                for(let input of addUpdate) {
                    input.value = this.book[input.getAttribute("id")]
                }
                document.querySelector(".form_addBook .fListBox header").innerText = this.book.bookList
                document.querySelector("#control_addBook").checked = true
                
                var change = new Event("change")
                fCheck.dispatchEvent(change)

            })
        }
    }
```

Comment: There will probably be an error if you look in the console. `heads` hasn't been defined.

Comment: I didn't put the whole code here. The 'heads' is defined.  The second photo is the print of that. @Andy

Comment: You should add the code for your `createBook` constructor to the question.

Comment: I've added it now @Andy